# Google sheets if cells contains text then return text

Tags: google-sheets

I have two cells A1 and A2 where the attributes can be High Risk, Medium Risk or Low Risk.  I'd like cell B2 to return the highest risk rating from A1 and A2.

So if A1="Medium Risk", A2="High Risk" then B2="High Risk"

If A1="Medium Risk", A2="Low Risk", then B2="Medium Risk"

How can I do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve that.. In B2 enter this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(choose(max(match(regexextract(A1:B1, "(.+)\s"), {"Low", "Medium", "High"},0)), "Low", "Medium", "High")& " Risk")
```

and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an auxiliary table where the rating of each risk is explicitly stated, e.g.

```
Risks!A1:B3
ColA; ColB
0; Low Risk
1; Medium Risk
2; High Risk
```

Then I would work with the numerical values like so:

```
RiskCalculations!A1:C4
ColA;ColB;ColC
Risk1; Risk2; Calculation
1; 0; =vlookup(max(A2,B2),Risks!A1:B3,2,FALSE)
0; 0; =vlookup(max(A3,B3),Risks!A1:B3,2,FALSE)
```

etc.

If you wanted to show the risks explicitly even during the calculations, then you need to nest `VLOOKUP()` before passing the values to `MAX()`

```
RiskCalculations!A1:C4
ColA;ColB;ColC
Risk1; Risk2; Calculation
Medium Risk; Low Risk; =vlookup(max(vlookup(Risks!A1:B3,A2,2,FALSE),vlookup(B2,Risks!A1:B3,2,FALSE)),Risks!A1:B3,2,FALSE)
Low Risk; Low Risk; =vlookup(max(vlookup(Risks!A1:B3,A3,2,FALSE),vlookup(B3,Risks!A1:B3,2,FALSE)),Risks!A1:B3,2,FALSE)
```

but then you need swap column A and column B to make it work (since `VLOOKUP()` uses the first column in the range as the index)

The advantage of this approach is that is flexible if you expand the risks you're including, or want to rephrase the text.